# How to wrap divs with CSS?

Tags: html, css, stack

Trying to build a simple login screen that would "friendly" both on a desktop and handheld devices. The main login section should just contain a label with a text box to the right and a <kbd>Continue</kbd> button under the text box. The tricky bit is I would like to see each wrap as the screen size is reduced. That is, if it is narrow enough, each control should appear 'stacked' on top of one another.

One a wide screen (sorry for the crude picture)

Enter Login: [                ]
                      |Continue|

On a narrow screen:

Enter Login: 
[                ]
 |Continue|

I have tried several combinatsion of divs, floated to the left, but I can't quite get the look above. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: I suggestion you Google 'responsive frameworks'  Look at bootstrap and others, they are already doing all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

People hate tables... but try one...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="index.html" method="get">
              First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
              Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS grid with a media query to achieve this.
jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/retavuy/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="loginp-page">
        <h1 class="login-title">Login</h1>
        <form action="#" class="login-form"> 
            <label for="login">Enter login</label>
            <input type="text" id="login">

            <button type="submit" class="button">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
main {
    padding-top: 1rem;
}

.login-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #ff5454;
}

.login-form {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-auto-rows: 2rem;

}

.login-form label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.login-form label,
.login-form input {
    display: block;
}

.login-form input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    font: inherit;
}

.login-form input:focus,
.login-form select:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: #ece7e7;
    border-color: #2ddf5c;
}

.login-form button[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
    .login-form {
        margin: auto;
        width: 30rem;
        grid-template-columns: 10rem auto;        
    }

   .login-form button[type="submit"] {
       grid-column: 1 / 3;     
   }
}
```